# Filtering multi-year dates in Shiny Datatable

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, dplyr, dt

I am running into an issue I can't quite resolve when filtering my Datatable in shiny.

I am displaying two dataframes, first is all the rows of the dataframe filtered for the time by a dateRangeInput filter. The second one is using the same data set and dateRangeInput, but summating the totals during the period. The user therefore gets the raw + summarized data on the page.

```
     update.df = eventReactive(input$Submit, {
     data() %>% filter (between( as.Date(Date), input$dateRange[1], input$dateRange[2]))
     })
```

This is my code for the first dataframe - I've also used this code prior to attempting the above:

```
     update.df = eventReactive(input$Submit, {
     data() %>% filter(as.Date(Date) >= as.Date(input$dateRange[1]) & as.Date(Date) <= as.Date(input$dateRange[2]))
      })
```

Whenever the dates fall within a calendar year, or same month, I find that the filters tend to work and the right subset of data is pulled. However, when the data spans two calendar years, I am missing months of data.

For example:

Date 1: Sep/01/2018

Date 2: Apr/30/2019

When I run these two dates, I am missing the dates from Jan 1st, 2019 to Apr 30th, 2019.

I believe the issue initially was that as I filtered using this:

```
as.Date(Date) <= as.Date(input$dateRange[2])
```

for the second part of my filter logic, the months that are 'less' than Apr 30th occur after that in the calendar year. But really, with the data I am using, the months between January - April occur earlier. That's why I eventually shifted to using 'between' hoping it would identify all dates in between the two spans. However, I am still not achieving the correct results.

How can I properly structure the filter logic so that when I filter the dataframe between Sep/01/2018 and Apr/30/2019, all the months that occur linearly show up in the dataframe as part of the subset?